# C# Property that returns interface type when accessed through an interface, and concrete type when accessed through concrete class

Tags: c#

I'm trying to construct a composite object behind composite interfaces, where if you access through the interface you get interfaces, and if you access through the concrete object you get concrete objects.

This code should hopefully make it clear what I'm trying to do:

```
public interface IA
{
  IB B { get; }
}

public interface IB
{
  [...stuff...]
}

public class CA: IA
{
  public CB B { get; private set; }
}

public class CB: IB
{
  [...stuff...]
}

public class Consumers
{
  // this consumer acts on the interface generically
  void InterfaceConsumer(IA a)
  {
    IB b = a.B;
  }

  // this consumer is necessarily tightly coupled to one particular concrete class and components
  void ConcreteConsumer(CA a)
  {
    CB b = a.B;
  }
}
```

Since CB is an IB I don't quite understand why the compiler doesn't let me do that.  I can add some other property/field to CA in order to allow the ConcreteConsumer to get at the concrete type, but that litters the concrete interface with more entrypoints, and requires more overhead writing and reading the consumers.  Is there a 'right' way of doing this?

Comment: Probably this is what you need: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation

Comment: That looks like the right answer, you want to take a go at turning it into a real answer for the credits?  I added a private field and then the concrete property and the explicit interface implementation and it seems to be going well so far for me...

Comment: I'm from mobile, so cannot craft actual answer right now :) But you can answer yourself for future readers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add explicit interface implementation in CA.

```cs
public CA: IA
{
   public CB B { get; }
   IB IA.B { get => B; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a generic interface implementing a non generic one and hiding the member from non generic one:

```
    public interface IA
    {
        IB B { get; }
    }

    public interface IA<TB> : IA
        where TB : IB
    {
        new TB B { get; } // Here, the new keyword hides IB B { get; }
    }
```

Now you can declare class CA as:

```
public class CA : IA<CB>
{
    IB IA.B { get { return B; } }

    public CB B { get; private set; }
}
```

Note that implementation of the base interface (the first property) is implemented explicitly, so that it is accessible only when programming against the interface. The `B` it returns is of type `CB`.

Now this compiles:

```
public class Consumers
{
    void InterfaceConsumer(IA a)
    {
        IB b = a.B;
    }

    void ConcreteConsumer(CA a)
    {
        CB b = a.B;
        IB ib = a.B; // This also works.
    }
}
```

However, you can always assign a `CB` to a `IA`, so the question is whether you really need such a construction.

Comment: I don't think you need the generic type involved?

Comment: It is not strictly needed; however, it ensures that all the members of the interface are also implemented against the concrete type and VS automatically implements both of them through the "Implement interface" smart tag.

Comment: I think I'm going to accept the simpler answer as the "correct" one for now, although this answer gives me more to chew on.